# MySQL Select Average weekly data from 6:00 p.m. to 8:00 a.m

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT temperature
FROM Temp_data
WHERE reading_time >= '$date' - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
  AND reading_time <= '$date' + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

| temperature | reading_time |
| --- | --- |
| 25.6 | 2022-01-03 18:03:05 |
| 24.9 | 2022-01-03 18:13:05 |
| 25.3 | 2022-01-03 18:23:05 |
| ... | ... |
| 29.6 | 2022-01-04 07:53:05 |

This data is only for one day. If wanting to fetch average temperature data between 18:00 - 8:00 in every day and average it in the form of the week for that month. How can I query the data to get it this way?

(EXPECT)

| Average temperature | week_start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 25.4 | 2021-12-01 |
| 25.5 | 2021-12-05 |
| 26.3 | 2021-12-12 |
| 26.4 | 2021-12-19 |
| 26.1 | 2021-12-26 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, AVG().

Comment: You also have to be more explicit as to what you mean by average: Do you mean *the average of the temperature values* present in the dataset, or *the average temperature* as best as can be given based on the values in the dataset.

Comment: I don't know how to explain. I just don't want the average of all average temperatures each day. I want the average temperature of the whole week in nighttime (6:00 pm -8:00 am).

Comment: I try avg() and group by(),but It didn't work for time period between that day night and the morning of the following day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    AVG(b.temperature) AS 'Average temperature',
    DATE(b.reading_time) AS 'week_start_date'
FROM (
    SELECT a.temperature, a.reading_time
    FROM temp_data a
    WHERE TIME(a.reading_time) > '18:00:00' OR TIME(a.reading_time) < '08:00:00'    
) b
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(b.reading_time, '%u')
```

Result (with random temperature data):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I get it!!

Comment: @rockstarmeekice thank you for accepting my answer, you can upvote it also